# Missing fonts in sticky notes of Adobe Reader in Wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux, adobe-reader

I have been using Adobe Reader XI with Wine (Playonlinux) without much problems. But serious problems arise when I use comment tools such as sticky notes. Please see the image for an example. There are two problems in this image marked by red ovals:

1. When the mouse hover over the sticky note with content "test", the content does not show up. But an empty bar shows up instead.
2. When there are Asian characters in the sticky note, it shows up as empty boxes both in the comment list and in the detail box of the sticky note.

Note that Asian characters in the main text actually show up correctly. And I have installed the extended font package, as seen from the Playonlinux script attached below. BTW, I have tried other wine versions as well as Adobe Reader DC, but they do not help. Can anyone tell me how I can solve these problems? Thanks a lot!

[Figure: Missing fonts in sticky notes of Adobe Reader in Wine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTakN.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env playonlinux-bash
# Date : (2015-11-02 15-09)
# Last revision : (2019-02-26 14-50)
# Wine version used : 3.20
# Distribution used to test : Debian 9.8
# Author : Hongcheng Ni

[ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

TITLE="Adobe Acrobat Reader XI"
PREFIX="AdobeAcrobatReaderXI"
WINEVERSION="3.20"
EDITOR="Adobe Systems Inc."
GAME_URL="https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/products/pdf-reader.html"
AUTHOR="Hongcheng Ni"


# Initialization
POL_SetupWindow_Init

POL_Debug_Init

# Presentation
# POL_GetSetupImages "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/top.jpg" "http://files.playonlinux.com/resources/setups/$PREFIX/left.jpg" "$TITLE"
POL_SetupWindow_presentation "$TITLE" "$EDITOR" "$GAME_URL" "$AUTHOR" "$PREFIX"

# Create Prefix
POL_System_TmpCreate "$PREFIX"

POL_SetupWindow_InstallMethod "DOWNLOAD,LOCAL"

if [ "$INSTALL_METHOD" = "LOCAL" ]
then
    POL_SetupWindow_browse "$(eval_gettext 'Please select $TITLE install file.')" "$TITLE"
    INSTALLER_EXE="$APP_ANSWER"
    POL_SetupWindow_browse "$(eval_gettext 'Please select $TITLE font pack file.')" "$TITLE"
    FONTPACK_EXE="$APP_ANSWER"
elif [ "$INSTALL_METHOD" = "DOWNLOAD" ]
then
    cd "$POL_System_TmpDir"
    POL_Download "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.10/en_US/AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe" "31688efbc3b9c99914a5bb7fb58aec9e"
    POL_Download "ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/11.x/11.0.09/misc/FontPack11009_XtdAlf_Lang.msi" "51c08dd56aaec1999f27de05e118127f"
    INSTALLER_EXE="$POL_System_TmpDir/AdbeRdr11010_en_US.exe"
    FONTPACK_EXE="$POL_System_TmpDir/FontPack11009_XtdAlf_Lang.msi"
fi

# Create Prefix
POL_Wine_SelectPrefix "$PREFIX"
POL_Wine_PrefixCreate "$WINEVERSION"

# Configuration
Set_OS "winxp"

# Dependencies
POL_Call POL_Install_atmlib
POL_Call POL_Install_riched20
POL_Call POL_Install_wsh57
POL_Call POL_Install_mspatcha
POL_Call POL_Install_vcrun2013
POL_Call POL_Install_FontsSmoothRGB

# Installation
POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"

Set_OS "win7"

POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext 'NOTICE: Please disable updating while installing.')" "$TITLE"

POL_Wine "$INSTALLER_EXE"

POL_Wine_WaitExit "$TITLE"

Set_OS "winxp"
POL_Wine_reboot

POL_Shortcut "AcroRd32.exe" "$TITLE"
POL_Shortcut_QuietDebug "$TITLE"

POL_SetupWindow_message "$(eval_gettext 'NOTICE: Please choose \"Always open with Protected Mode disabled.\" while starting the program for the first time.')" "$TITLE"

# Install font pack
POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"

Set_OS "win7"

POL_AutoWine "$FONTPACK_EXE"

POL_Wine_WaitExit "$TITLE"

Set_OS "winxp"
POL_Wine_reboot
POL_System_TmpDelete

POL_SetupWindow_Close
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing the Segoe fonts (e.g. from [here](https://github.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui-linux/tree/master/font)) solved the problem.