# How to get latest version of acrobat reader (not acrobat reader 9)

Tags: 20.04, adobe

I am using acrobat reader 9 and I notice that this version is from 2013! I am wondering how I can get the LATEST version of acrobat reader in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Adobe no longer supports Acrobat Reader for Linux. The latest native Linux version is 9.5.5 dated from 26/04/2013, as you correctly stated in your question. Maybe, the only chance to use a newer version is installaing the Windows version through Wine, but this is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Do you need it for something special, quite a few readers for linux, Ubuntu has one already installed and most main browsers have ability to read also now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have already know about native 9.5.5 which is old.

The other option is to install Acrobat Reader using Wine. Also we know that it fails to access files from `/tmp` while using [`acrordrdc`](https://snapcraft.io/acrordrdc) snap package.

So we need to install it manually using Wine and PlayOnLinux. Below is how:

1. Install PlayOnLinux

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
2. Launch PlayOnLinux
3. Click *Install*, enter `acrobat` into the search field
4. Select *Adobe Acrobat Reader DC* for installation
5. Proceed with one of the following:

   - download Acrobat Reader DC 2020 standalone installer from https://get.adobe.com/ru/reader/enterprise/ to get file named [AcroRdrDC2000920063_en_US.exe](http://ardownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/AcrobatDC/2000920063/AcroRdrDC2000920063_en_US.exe) and choose it on the corresponding step of wizard;
   - allow wizard to download Acrobat Reader DC 2015 by itself
6. Wait wizard to finish.
7. To get all fonts and remove visual artifacts save the code below to some file - for example `~/Downloads/acrordrc2020.pol` with [contents](https://gist.github.com/N0rbert/63ca7636559ebc22831933cd78b0c8e2) below

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env playonlinux-bash

   [ "$PLAYONLINUX" = "" ] && exit 0
   source "$PLAYONLINUX/lib/sources"

   TITLE="Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
   PREFIX="AdobeAcrobatReaderDC"
   WINEVERSION="4.0.3"
   EDITOR="Adobe Systems Inc."
   GAME_URL="https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/products/pdf-reader.html"
   AUTHOR="Martins Bruvelis, N0rbert (to support ARDC 2020)"

   POL_SetupWindow_Init
   POL_Debug_Init

   POL_SetupWindow_presentation "$TITLE" "$EDITOR" "$GAME_URL" "$AUTHOR" "$PREFIX"

   # select prefix
   POL_System_TmpCreate "$PREFIX"
   POL_Wine_SelectPrefix "$PREFIX"

   # setup prefix
   POL_Wine_InstallFonts
   POL_Call POL_Install_atmlib
   POL_Call POL_Install_corefonts
   #POL_Call POL_Install_allfonts
   POL_Call POL_Install_wsh57
   POL_Call POL_Install_mspatcha
   POL_Call POL_Install_riched30
   POL_Call POL_Install_riched20
   POL_Call POL_Install_gdiplus
   POL_Call POL_Install_FontsSmoothRGB
   POL_Call POL_Install_d3dx11
   POL_Call POL_Install_d3dx10
   POL_Call POL_Install_directx9

   POL_Wine_WaitBefore "$TITLE"
   POL_Wine_WaitExit "$TITLE"

   POL_SetupWindow_Close
   exit
   ```
8. In the PlayOnLinux window select *Tools* → *Run a local script* and specify path to it (`~/Downloads/acrordrc2020.pol`), confirm its execution and wait it to finish.
9. Set file association for PDF file with Acrobat in PlayOnLinux by choosing *Settings* → *File Associations*, then click *New*, enter *.pdf* and associate it with Acrobat in the bottom of window.
10. Open file manager, select PDF file and use *Open With* to get it opened using newly installed Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.
11. Enjoy:

    > [image: ARDC2020]

Comment: Its sad i'll have to use wine/playonlinux to install the latest version! I really hope Windows/MAC OS developers start developing there apps for the linux platform!

Comment: in step 9 I had to enter `.pdf` to see the extension in the list

Comment: thanks for the writeup, but in the end, the whole thing is somewhat shaky and I'm not able to use certain features at all (e.g. clicking on Sign & Fill it always crashes)

Comment: Note that to for annotations to work properly, I needed to [install the Segoe fonts](https://askubuntu.com/a/1314105/145802).

Comment: Made my day.. 1G of open source (no ads) executables.. Lighter than winapp as KVM (https://github.com/Fmstrat/winapps)

Comment: Any idea how to get Adobe Reader to recognize the printer on Ubuntu?

Comment: I press Ctrl+P and it shows all my printers which were previously added to system.

Answer (score 0):

might try :

```
:~$ sudo snap install acrordrdc
:~$ acrordrdc
```

Source : [How to Install Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (WINE) on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

Comment: If the Acrobat Reader DC installation through snap is failing. It means your system snap/snapd is not functioning properly. and since snap/snapd is highly dependent on systemd & Openssh-client implementation. you may need to look into those issues and resolve them before fixing your snap environment.

Comment: how to configure it? used `playonlinux` doesn't work, `crossover` work but chargable (not free)

Answer (score -1):

You already *have* the latest version. There is no newer one. Adobe stopped supporting Linux many, many years ago.