# Acrobat Reader DC - Freezes when commenting

Tags: snap, adobe-acrobat

I've installed the latest version of Adobe Acrobat DC that is available through Snap. I've fixed the issue with the fonts. However, the program crashes when I try and type on a comment or a sticky note. The comment window appears just fine. The problem is when I type the first letter in it. The program then appears unresponsive and then I have to force quit it.

Has anyone else encountered that and if yes how did you solve it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get latest version of acrobat reader (not acrobat reader 9)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263864/how-to-get-latest-version-of-acrobat-reader-not-acrobat-reader-9)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04.

I've also tried the PlayOnLinux approach and had no luck either. It didn't crash but it did not display any text in the comments.